# Breeze.Sharp ContextProvider for RavenDB

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

> Your backend data services
>
> BreezeSharp communicates with any service that speaks HTTP and JSON.
>   Are you serving data with Web API, OData or MVC backed by Entity
>   Framework in front of SQL Server? Breeze has a great out-of-the-box
>   story. Running SharePoint, Node, or Rails? You’re covered. NHibernate?
>   Yes. Mongo? You bet. Raven, Azure Tables, Couch, FireBase, Postgress?
>   Java? No problem. Something we haven’t tried yet? Bring it! Consuming
>   a 3rd party service that you can’t change? BreezeSharp adapts. There
>   are no BreezeSharp server-side components.

[From Breeze.Sharp website](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-sharp/about)

Although your website says backend dataservices for RavenDB available, I dont think there is any. Is there any plan to release a ContextProvider for RavenDB like EFContextProvider for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text on the website IS misleading. The idea is that anyone can create a backend to talk to breeze from any server side technology. i.e that the breeze client is agnostic about what backend it talks to.

Some of these backends have already been built, such as Entity Framework and NHibernate on .NET and MongoDb on Node.  We also have prototype versions of backends for Java and PHP.

Unfortunately, no one has yet done this for RavenDB but you can vote for the feature here:

https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3233261-ravendb-support-similar-to-ef

Alternatively, you can contact breeze@ideablade.com consulting services and have them to write a custom version of this provider.

Comment: After reading more about Breeze, the concept of using an adapter at the server seems is similar to RIA. In RIA, the PersistChanges can be overridden to store the changes to any database, but there is also an adapter that can talk to the particular DB required.